# Finding Time Connected in Seconds

Tags: c#, .net, c++, time

When someone connects to my TCP Server, I log the time they connected using

```
System.DateTime dt = System.DateTime.Now;
```

Then when I need to find how long they have been connected, I do...

```
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, System.DateTime> pair in playerList)
    {
         System.DateTime curTime = System.DateTime.Now;
         float connectedTime = (float)(curTime - pair.Value).TotalSeconds;
         writer.Write(connectedTime);
    }
```

When I debug the value of connectedTime looks correct, but the protocol I am using to report it is seeing it as gibberish.

The C++ code I use which works fine is...

```
time_t currentTime = time(NULL);
time_t connectedTime = currentTime - g_Users.Element(i).connectTime;
g_UserInfo.WriteFloat(float(tempTime));
```

Am I doing something silly?

Comment: What is `writer.Write(float val)` doing?

Comment: Not enough info. What is `writer`? What is "the protocol I am using to report it"?

Comment: Possibly the representation of the float in C# on the server is different to the representation of the float in (another language?) on (another server?)

Comment: Are you accessing float.TotalSeconds? I'm not entirely sure whether the cast or the property access takes precedence in C#, `(float)((curTime - pair.Value).TotalSeconds)` would be less ambiguous IMHO.

Comment: writer is BinaryWriter, sorry.

Comment: The protocol is http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server_queries#A2S_PLAYER

Comment: what do you mean by "protocol" and "gibberish" ? maybe the "protocol" does not know how to reconstruct the float value.

Comment: @Mufaka: BinaryWriter does have Write(float) method!

Comment: Where are you reading this float value? Maybe you need to convert it first from Host to Network byte order...

Comment: @Mufaka: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7cxfc93.aspx  C# `float` is `System.Single`.

Comment: @Mufaka: There is no `int` either!!! Thats because native type of `float` is `Single` like `int` is the same as `Int32` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7cxfc93.aspx

Comment: Sorry all, looks like I was forgetting to add "\0" to my string which broke the rest of the packet design. Thank you for the help!

Comment: haha, my apologies! I was absolutely stumped looking at all of the time related code, completely missed the bigger picture on that one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to cast to float, as you are using the `BinarryWirter` the `Write` method can take any integral type: `double`, `float`, `int`.., So:

```
writer.Write((DateTime.Now.Subtract(pair.Value)).TotalSeconds);
```